# No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint, moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, srdf, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am importing a 6 DOF arm using setupAssistant. When I load the urdf for the robotic arm, all the parts of the robotic arm are at the same plane. It shows a message  "No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint".

I searched in other threads and came across that there is some information to be added in the SRDF file.
Since I have generated the URDF from Solidworks, so please tell where should I create a SRDF for the same and whether we have to load the URDF or the SRDF of the robot to fix this.

Here are the console logs:

```
[ INFO] [1400146129.617803918]: Loaded robot robot model.
[ INFO] [1400146129.618207340]: Setting Param Server with Robot Description
[ INFO] [1400146129.632349428]: Robot semantic model successfully loaded.
[ INFO] [1400146129.632505515]: Setting Param Server with Robot Semantic Description
[ INFO] [1400146129.664284638]: Loading robot model 'robot'...
[ INFO] [1400146129.664376122]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1400146130.118231108]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1400146130.118454828]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ INFO] [1400146130.830133313]: Loading robot model 'robot'...
[ INFO] [1400146130.830429200]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1400146131.398639691]: Loading robot model 'robot'...
[ INFO] [1400146131.398745909]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1400146131.688112326]: Loading Setup Assistant Complete
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165136/no-root-joint-specified.-assuming-fixed-joint,-moveit/) by [rvijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18021/rvijay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clark_txh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28091/clark_txh/) on 2016-09-30**:
hello
I get the same proplem, can you tell me ,how sovle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Strange as it may sound, when running [in debug mode using gdb](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_setup_assistant/blob/28228ca05e36ecf6131a964dbe1c66f11a0d8673/launch/setup_assistant.launch) worked around the issue for a person I was helping.

```
$ roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch debug:=true
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-24**:
You did not get the message `No root joint ..` when running the Setup Assistant in gdb?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-04-24**:
Not that I know of (this was happening on someone else' computer I was helping).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-24**:
That sounds rather strange: the message essentially tells you that there is no joint connecting `base_link` to the 'world' (however that is defined). Running in gdb or not should not affect this.